# Electrical shock with a live wire

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, electric-circuits, capacitance

If a person were to touch a live wire while on an insulated platform, the resistance shoukd prevent any current flow. However, I have read that there is capacitative coupling voltage. I have studied capacitors but there is probably something I am missing here since even if I consider my body and the ground as capacitor walls with the insulatiin as trapped dielectric yet there is no complete path in the sense that one capacitor plate has an alternating voltage but the other does not. So why should any current ( displacement current?) should flow through capacitors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current through a capacitor is

$$i = C \frac{dv}{dt}$$

i.e the current is proportional to the CHANGE in voltage. If there is AC voltage, then  there is always change in voltage and hence current will flow through the capacitor (and through the person, which is part of the circuit.

The capacitor voltage is the difference between the potential on both sides. On the "down" side, the potential is simply "ground", and the "life" side, it's whatever the AC voltage is at a given point in time.

Answer (score 1):

> If a person were to touch a live wire while on an insulated platform,
> the resistance should prevent any current flow.

If a person were to touch an ac live wire while on an insulated platform, the resistance of the platform would prevent current flow, but its capacitance would permit current flow.
That's because the insulating platform impedance can be modeled as combination of a capacitor in parallel with a resistor and a spark gap.

Current through the platform is therefore the sum of the resistively coupled current and capacitively coupled current through the platform. (The spark gap represents the dielectric strength of the insulating material. It only plays a potential role at very high voltages where the insulation breaks down providing a low impedance path for current to flow.)

Hope this helps.